# EKS not able to authenticate to Kubernetes with Kubectl - "User: is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've initially run `aws --region eu-west-1 eks update-kubeconfig --name prod-1234 --role-arn arn:aws:iam::1234:user/chris-devops` to get access to the EKS cluster.

When doing anything like: `kubectl get ...` I get an error of:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole
>   operation: User: arn:aws:iam::1234:user/chris-devops is not authorized
>   to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource:
>   arn:aws:iam::1234:user/chris-devops

Why do I get this error? How do I gain access?

I've added the following to the user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1234:user/chris-devops"
        }
    ]
}
```

In addition I also have full Administrator access:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've read through: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_roles.html#troubleshoot_roles_cant-assume-role

And my understanding is I'm meeting all the criteria.

Comment: try to change `"Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1234:user/chris-devops` to `"Resource":*`

Comment: Thanks - I did actually have that there initially but no no difference.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://eksworkshop.com/irsa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aws eks --region eu-west-1 update-kubeconfig --name prod-eks-3flXvI2r --role-arn http://arn:aws:iam::1234:role/prod-eks-1234-admins
```

I had to specify the correct role... Woohooo

Comment: Yes and to add more details, you need to specify the role that provisioned the EKS cluster. Same in the policy of your user, use the provision role.

Comment: how did you create this role? if I understand right this role meaning should be eks to access your account.

Answer (score 2):

Your policy is wrong. User can’t assume another IAM user. It should be something like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/prod-Eks-1234-admins"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: how did you create this role? if I understand right this role meaning should be eks to access your account. 

what policy attached to this role? the Prod-Eks-1234-admins

Thanks!